# Error . InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'. Having trouble pulling data from the firebase

Tags: angular

I am using angular 5 currently. It is giving me a pipe error . I believe there is a conflict in the versions and i guess the video that i referred to is using angular 4. The error that I am gettin is Error . InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'.

**This is the .ts file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, List } from 'ionic 
angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {Profile} from '../../model/profile';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
import { UserprofilePage } from '../userprofile/userprofile';

@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-editprofile',
  templateUrl: 'editprofile.html',
})
export class EditprofilePage {

  profile = {}
  as Profile;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  createProfile() {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.object(`user/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile)
        .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot(UserprofilePage))
    })
  }

}
```

**this is the .html file where the data should be displayed.**

**This is the profile page**

```
<p> Name : {{(profileData | async) ?. name}}</p>
<p> Location : {{(profileData | async) ?. location}}</p>
<p> Pets : {{(profileData | async) ?. pets}}</p>
<p> Gallery : {{(profileData | async) ?. gallery}}</p>
<p> About me : {{(profileData | async) ?. aboutme}}</p>
```

This is the .ts file of the profilepage

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 
'ionic-angular';
import { EditprofilePage } from '../editprofile/editprofile';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 
'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Profile } from '../../model/profile';
import { auth } from 'firebase';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-userprofile',
templateUrl: 'userprofile.html',
})
export class UserprofilePage {





profileData : AngularFireObject<Profile>

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
private afDatabase : AngularFireDatabase , private afAuth : 
AngularFireAuth , private toast:ToastController) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
//console.log('ionViewDidLoad UserprofilePage');
this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
  if (data && data.email && data.uid){
    this.toast.create({
      message: `Welcome,${data.email}`,
      duration :3000

    }).present();
    this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`user/${data.uid}`)
  }
  else {
    this.toast.create({
      message : `No auth details`,
      duration :  3000
    }).present() ; 
   }
   })


   }

  changeprofile(){
  this.navCtrl.push(EditprofilePage);

  }

  }
```

[The reference video I referred to.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uESqBwFVf1Q&t=30s)

Comment: Not able to see the `profileData` profile in your Page code. Please add the TS code for your `ProfilePage`

Comment: `profileData` must be an `Observable<Profile>` to use async pipe not just a `Profile` object.

Comment: `this.afDatabase.object<Profile>(`user/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges()`

Comment: Hello Adam, welcome to StackOverflow! Firstly, it's a good idea to use normal single quotations (`'`) when you're not binding variables to the string. Secondly, please consider properly indenting your code so that others can understand your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is slightly change in the latest version of Angular Firebase. `list`,`object` etc doesn't return the Observable so you need to use `valueChanges()` to return an observable.

```
this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`user/${data.uid}`)
```

to

```
this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`user/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
```

Comment: Could you please consider explaining what your code does? This can help aid others in what your code does vs the OP's code.

Comment: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireObject<Profile>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}>'.
(property) UserprofilePage.profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>. 

this.profileData is giving the red line . ( The above is the problem when i hover over it. )

Comment: I am trying to receive data from the firebase . I believe its the version difference that is throwing me off . I can send the data to the firebase but having trouble receiving

Comment: Change your declaration from `profileData : AngularFireObject<Profile>` to `profileData : Observable <any>`